# How to read log file time by time and extract the specific line not containning date info

Tags: python, algorithm, logging, readfile

I have a log file and the format of it would be like this,

```
INFO    2018/11/20 18:56:00 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
INFO    2018/11/20 18:56:00 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
INFO    2018/11/20 18:56:00 cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
INFO    2018/11/20 18:56:00 ddddddddddddddddddddddd
WARN    2018/11/20 18:56:23 Some Error Message
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: blahblahblah
INFO    2018/11/20 19:01:23 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

I don't care about the normal log but I want to extract the line containing "Exception" word, which is sould be written at some point (like between 18:00:00 and 18:59:59.)
What I thought af first was to get index using enumerate function while reading the log file. But with this, I have to read the file at least more that three times. And also linecache functions loads every line in the file on memory. Some files are more than 100MB so I know it is bad idea.

```
start = 0
end = 0
with open("filename", "f") as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        if re.search("2018(\/|:|)11(\/|:|)20 18:\d{2}:\d{2}", line):
            start = idx
            break

    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        if re.search("2018(\/|:|)11(\/|:|)20 19:\d{2}:\d{2}", line):
            end = idx - 1
            break    

for i in range(start, end):
    line = linecache.getline("filename", i)
    if 'Exception' in line:
        print line
```

The most critical problem is that logs are not always written on xx:00m or xx:59m. For example, it would be started on 18:01:00 or 18:03:31..

I haven't come up with any good idea since yesterday. Please help me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you you want exactly as output? If it's just the line containing the exception why are you searching for time strings?

Comment: Enumerating your file requires reading the whole file anyway, making linecache useless, I think simply searching the file is your best bet.

If you only want a specific time range, a possible solution is to use a bisection search to find the start and end points, then scan all lines in between with linecache.

Comment: Rereading the docs, it seems linecache is not for this purpose, it's meant for python source files. This seems to apply even to python2, even though the doc says otherwise. From the linecache module source: `This is intended to read lines from modules imported`.

Also, for 100MB, it's not really that big a file, so reading line by line as in posted answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Eric Thank you! I didn't know that enumerating alos requires reading the whole file and it is good chance to know linecache exactly thanks to you!

Comment: Eh, wait, I'm wrong. I should clarify. Enumerate is a generator, so it works lazily, I didn't realise that you had a break in the for loop. It does mean that it'll read everything until the line that you're looking for, so linecache is still useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really have to loop over the file 3 times. 
Just maintain the current and previous line in your loop.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

result = OrderedDict()

with open("filename", "r") as f:
    prev, curr = None, None
    for id, line in enumerate(f):
        prev = curr
        curr = line
        if re.search('Exception', line):
            if re.search('18:\d{2}:\d{2}', prev):
                result[id] = line

print(result)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([(5, 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: blahblahblah\n')])
```

If you wish to get line number of all the 1 hour slots from your log file, then you just have to replace `'18'` with some variable.

Comment: Thank you! this is what I am looking for and what I couldn't think :) Cna you please explain more about replacing '18' with some variable? @eiram_mahera

Comment: by replace 18, it's probably replace the 18 in here `'18:\d{2}:\d{2}'` with a string substitution/formatting. Unfortunately, since it also contains curly braces {} which are used for string formatting, the simplest way is something like `x=18` `str(x) + ':\d{2}:\d{2}'` So if you want a different timing, just replace the variable with another number

Answer (score 0):

Can you just read the file line by line?

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line.find('Exception') >= 0:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Since you are already reading the whole file with `readlines` you can put the loop outside the `with open` block, this way you don't keep the file unnecessarily open

Comment: @richflow the time range shoulw be considered first T.T Thanks for the response!